# Is creating Stripe Payment Backend API secure?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, stripe-payments

I want to process Stripe payment to create stripe subscription.
For that I need to pass card number, expiration date, cvc to my backend api.
Is it secure to create Stripe payment this way?
If it is not secure, what methods can I use to secure the subscription request to the backend api?

Answer (score 2):

This is not recommended. Instead, you should collect payment details securely with [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/payments/elements) ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements))and use the safe IDs returned by that to collect payments.

If you are [PCI compliant](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance), you should contact [Stripe support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) for assistance with enabling your account to process card details directly.